# Running a unit test module in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line

I have a unit test. It's name is test_mymod.py

Snippet:

```
...
import mymod

import os
import unittest

class myTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
...
```

What is the correct way to run this test module command line? Python3.

I have not used Python in a few years and apparently forgot, a lot.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#basic-example

Comment: @Goyo I do not see the command line show in the example, could you point it out?

Comment: Just like any python script `python test_mymod.py` or maybe `python3 test_mymod.py` depending on your OS and setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3 -m unittest test_mymod.py` is one of possible ways to run `unittest`.

Comment: That's did something. passes  and failures.